# Getting wrong data while reading Bitmap image

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm following this tutorial
http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/how-to-load-a-bitmap-r1966 and I got the problem of wrong value for all the bitmap header/info that I load.

I've declared the structure to store the bitmap header, info

```
typedef struct BITMAPFILE_HEADER {
  WORD  bfType;
  DWORD   bfSize;
  WORD  bfReserved1;
  WORD  bfReserved2;
  DWORD   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILE_HEADER;

//Bitmap information header
//provides information specific to the image data
typedef struct BITMAPINFO_HEADER{
  DWORD  biSize;
  LONG   biWidth;
  LONG   biHeight;
  WORD   biPlanes;
  WORD   biBitCount;
  DWORD  biCompression;
  DWORD  biSizeImage;
  LONG   biXPelsPerMeter;
  LONG   biYPelsPerMeter;
  DWORD  biClrUsed;
  DWORD  biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFO_HEADER;

//Colour palette
typedef struct RGB_QUAD {
  BYTE  rgbBlue;
  BYTE  rgbGreen;
  BYTE  rgbRed;
  BYTE  rgbReserved;
} RGB_QUAD;
```

After that I read the bitmap by using following codes:

```
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("picture.bmp", "rb");

    if (in == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
    }
    else
    {
        BITMAPFILE_HEADER bmfh;
        BITMAPINFO_HEADER bmih;

        fread(&bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILE_HEADER), 1, in);
        fread(&bmih, sizeof(BITMAPINFO_HEADER), 1, in);

        if (bmih.biBitCount != 24)
            printf("not 24");
    }
```

My picture is 24-bit but when I run this program, it shows "not 24". I try to debug it in Visual Studio then I saw the `bmih.biBitCount` is `0`. In addition, the image width and height is wrong as well, the only correct data that I found in the header is the `bmfh.bfType` which is `19778`.

Anyone know what's wrong with my codes? 
Again, I just want to read the bmp but not displaying it.

PS:
Originally the picture is in JPEG format. I converted it to BMP format by using MS PAINT and re-save it in BMP format. I wonder does it affect the values?

Comment: What should the width and height be and what does the code say they are?  What bit count does the code report?

Comment: There are different versions of bitmap. I'm not sure what version paint uses, but you may want to check if its the same version. I know there are differences as I had written one that could read/write version 3 but many files are 6 and couldn't read it.

Comment: the image resolution is 1024 x 768
but the value that I got after reading the BMP is
width=50331648
height=65536
bitcount=0
planes=24

Comment: The linked article mentions that the structs are already defined and can be included with "#include <windows.h>". Since you're working with Visual Studio, are there reasons to declare the structures yourself?

Comment: thanks stefaanv, once again you pointed out my mistake. Yea, after using the structure that already defined in windows.h, it works perfectly!

Comment: @CadrickLoh: I guess the windows.h version is already packed and the defined structs in the article are more for documentation than to use directly.  But besides that, it can help to know about alignment issues for later development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that you ran into an [alignment issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), because the compiler can choose to align data in a structure as he sees fit.  You can try to pack your struct, but I would suggest to read out every field and fill it in separately, it is more work, but it is clearer and avoids alignment issues.

Comment: fread(&bmfh.bftype, sizeof(bmfh.bftype), 1, in);fread(&bmfh.bfsize, sizeof(bmfh.bfsize), 1, in);..., with checking the return value.

Comment: Wow it works like a charm!

Anyway, I would like to know how the filestreamer able to differentiate which one store in which variable? We just specify the sizeof then it will know where to put @@?

Comment: Oh I noticed the sequence of how I read the header is very important.